# How can I assign Administrator Module to different page other than main page?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am new to Joomla. I have to add an administrator module to the page where a specific module is being edited at administrator side. 
For example here is the module editing page where I want to add an Administrator module
[image: specific Module editing page]

But there isn't any option for `menu assignment` in administrator module editing page

[image: Admin module editing page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for administrator modules.

The admin template has set module positions which in turn, have set pages they're displayed on.

For example, if you assign a module to the `cpanel` position, it will only be displayed on the administrator Dashboard.